# Creating a TFS Project w/VS 2013 and receiving the following

Tags: tfs

Every time I try to create a new project, I receive the following error when applying the MSF For Agile Software Development 2013.2

> “The following element contains an error: TaskBacklog/States.
>   TF400587: This element defines the states for work items that appear
>   on your backlog. Each state must exist in at least one of the work
>   item types belong to category defined in: 'TaskBacklog/States'. The
>   following state does not exist in any of the work item types:
>   Resolved.”

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is your server upgraded recently? Have you customized the work item definition?

Comment: Not upgraded, but we do have custom WIT

Comment: Then you need to check if "Resolved" state is missed in the customized WIT.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same version of Visual Studio as your TFS installation. So if you're using TFS 2015, you need to create your project using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Thank you for the Reply, I confirmed that I'm using same version VS and TFS 2013.  It was working up until i would say two three weeks ago.